# VBA: For loop used for an array gives error

Tags: vba, excel

This following code gives me "For each control variable on arrays must be Variant" error. But ws_names is an array of variant, if I'm not mistaken. Can someone please explain? Thank you!

```
Public Sub test12()
    Dim ws_names() As Variant
    ws_names = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Dim ws_name As String
    For Each ws_name In ws_names()
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws_name).Visible = False
    Next ws_name
End Sub
```

Comment: The `ws_name` variable is declared as a `string`, and needs to be declared as a `Variable`.

Comment: Dim ws_name As Variant

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to loop through the array

```
Dim ws_names() As Variant
ws_names = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")

Sheets(ws_names).Visible = False
```

You can also use a one liner

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Visible = False
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code

```
Public Sub test12()

    Dim ws_names() As Variant
    ws_names = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Dim ws_name As Variant
    For Each ws_name In ws_names()
        'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws_name).Visible = False
        Debug.Print ws_name
    Next ws_name

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of a [For Each...Next Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) loop is: For Each *element* in *group* ... Next *element*

> For collections, element can only be a Variant variable, a generic object variable, or any specific object variable. **For arrays, element can only be a Variant variable.**

Thus, the following would work:

```
Public Sub test12()
    Dim ws_names() As Variant
    ws_names = Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Dim ws_name As Variant
    For Each ws_name In ws_names()
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws_name).Visible = False
    Next ws_name
End Sub
```

However, as @GMalc pointed out in their answer, a loop is not even necessary for this one.